# Titles to a wpf window - is there a convention?

Tags: c#, wpf, title

I'm almost ready with my billing program and therefore I used ADO.Net and WPF. Now I wonder if every WPF window should have the same title of the program or if they could have another title depending on whatever they do? Is there a convention for this?

e.g. My program would call billing program. I have a window to log in to your profile should it been called something like "Log in"?

Comment: I think you might have more luck finding good answers to this on UX: http://ux.stackexchange.com/search?q=window+title .

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's the answer I looked for.